# Search on Map data type with Value index in spring-data-aerospike

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-webflux, aerospike

It will be great to have some example for querying the MapValue index type in Spring using spring-data-aerospike with aerospike-reactor-client.

I have a customer defined as

```java
public class Customer {
  @Id private int id;

  @Indexed(
      name = "idxPartnerToken",
      type = IndexType.STRING,
      collectionType = IndexCollectionType.DEFAULT)
  private String partnerToken;

  @Field("externalRefs")
  @Indexed(type = STRING, collectionType = IndexCollectionType.MAPVALUES)
  Map<ExternalReferenceType, String> externalRefs;

  List<Segment> segments;

  private OffsetDateTime createdTime;
  private String createdBy;

  private OffsetDateTime updatedTime;
  private String updatedBy;
}
```

Using AQL

```sql
 SELECT * FROM test.customer IN MAPVALUES WHERE externalRefs = "56789"
```

Data:

```
+-----------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| PK        | externalRefs                      | @_class                                       | partnerToken          |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| "4049415" | MAP('{"LOCAL_CUSTOMER":"56789"}') | "com.test.customerservice.document.Customer" | "P-6924584.212981942" |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

I'm trying to get the data using below in repository

```java
Mono<Customer> findCustomerByExternalRefs(
      String externalReferenceId, CriteriaDefinition.AerospikeMapCriteria criteria);
```

I'm calling it

```java
customerReactiveAerospikeRepository.findCustomerByExternalRefs(
           "56789", CriteriaDefinition.AerospikeMapCriteria.VALUE);
```

But this return empty.

Although if I try to query with partnerToken it works

```java
customerReactiveAerospikeRepository.findCustomerByPartnerToken("P-6924584.212981942");
```

Can you suggest what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

Query by Map values is supported in `Spring Data Aerospike`.

Try to explicitly state the query type in the method's name - for example:

```java
List<Customer> customerReactiveAerospikeRepository.findCustomerByExternalRefsValuesContaining(String value);
```

An example of a repository that defines a Map key containing query (similar principles of Map value containing):
https://github.com/aerospike-community/spring-data-aerospike/blob/3.4.1/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/aerospike/sample/PersonRepository.java#L120

And a test (example) of Map value containing query using a reactive query engine under the hood:
https://github.com/aerospike-community/spring-data-aerospike/blob/3.4.1/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/aerospike/query/reactive/ReactiveQualifierTests.java#L450